# HealthStatuses are all reported as Invalid or Outdated

Tags: tapkey

we manage a sizeable number of locks in our accounts.

Recently we implemented a lock health overview using the BoundLocks ?expand=healthStatuses endpoint as described  by https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_access_management_web_api_v1/#/Bound%20Locks/BoundLocks_GetById

Couple of months later, and I notice that none of the reported valueStatus are marked OK but either 'Outdated' (with a timestamp of today) or 'Invalid' (with a much older timestamp).

I understand the invalid ones (locks in storage and so on), but I'm not sure why I'm seeing outdated references for locks that have timestamps for today.

The documentation gives no insight in what the differences are between Ok, Outdated or Invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug on Tapkey side. The fix will be published tomorrow forenoon, then the state should be again as expected.

Outdated means that the lock has not reported the value in the last 14 days.
Invalid means that the lock has reported a value which does not match the expected format. This would be a error on lock side.